# Razor pay integration and payment capture

Tags: adonisjs-ace

how to install razor pay in adonis js ?
how to  integrate in adonis js ?
How to capture razor pay payment in adonis js ?
how to get all payment details?
how to refund payment in razor pay?
how to get refund details and payment details ?